# porting iOS project for mac platform

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have been searching around for a method to port an iOS xcode built project to OSX xcode project. Unfortunately, I have found that because there is no UIKit or storyboard for OSX xcode (just individual .xib's). Is there a way around this?

Comment: But there's AppKit and documentation, and that's more than enough.

Comment: Or you can just target the iOS Simulator and boom your iPhone app runs on OS X...

Comment: @H2CO3 I hope you're being facetious!

Comment: @Marko I always am, practically.

Answer (score 5):

If you're a registered Apple developer there's a new video up that goes through some of the basics and the design patterns you should be aware of, just named "Bringing Your iOS Apps To OS X".

Answer (score 2):

The UI paradigm of any non-trivial iOS applications is entirely different to that of one for MacOSX.

Necessarily, you will need to redesign the View layer of the application.  However, the Model layer ought to cleanly port over and at least some of your controller classes might be reusable, although MacOSX doesn't have anything equivalent to a `UIViewContoller`.

Besides this, many of the frameworks your app might be using are either available for both iOS and MacOSX (usually in cut-down form on the former), or a similar.

Comment: Well, technically there is NSViewController.

Answer (score 0):

If your logic and UI are well separated, you have a chance at some good re-use, but at a minimum you will need to rebuild the UI layers of your app; it's going to take time.

If you don't have the time to invest, and if you are willing to try something experimental, there are a couple 3rd party frameworks available that attempt to bridge the UIKit AppKit gap.

You can probably consider many of these as risky 'shots in the dark', but they are worth a look.  Keep in mind the long term support ramifications as well.

- [Chameleon](http://chameleonproject.org/)
- [UMEKit](http://parsekit.com/umekit/)